# Issue with Task Scheduler starting Task Compability module

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-7-x64

Have this error in the System log on Windows 7：Task Scheduler service failed to start Task Compatibility module. Tasks may not be able to register on previous Window versions. Additional Data: Error Value:2147942405.

The Event ID is 701.

Have no idea how to fix this error.